# AWS RDS PostgreSQL with Python 3.8 version with Zappa

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, zappa

I am trying to deploy Zappa app for connecting AWS RDS to PostgreSQL using Python. When we execute from the code from the terminal the code works fine and RDS gets connected to PostgreSQL. But when I try to execute the code in Zappa, it throws the following error:

**Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 502 response code.**

The **zappa_settings.json** file is given below:

```
    "dev": {
        "app_function": "app.app",
        "aws_region": "ap-south-1",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "project_name": "rds-postgres-py",
        "runtime": "python3.8",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-aoxdyg89v"
    }
}
```

The log of deployment using **zappa tail** is given here:

```
[1665576386682] [DEBUG] 2022-10-12T12:06:26.682Z 662d3c73-766e-45ec-87c4-d9caeeb9a143 Zappa Event: {'time': '2022-10-12T12:06:08Z', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': '891890779389', 'region': 'ap-south-1', 'detail': {}, 'version': '0', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:ap-south-1:891890779389:rule/rds-postgres-py-dev-zappa-keep-warm-handler.keep_warm_callback'], 'id': '32e22a30-3a4f-07c0-9613-c523351b5484', 'kwargs': {}}
[1665576386682] [DEBUG] 2022-10-12T12:06:26.682Z 662d3c73-766e-45ec-87c4-d9caeeb9a143 Zappa Event: {}
[1665576404722] Instancing..
[1665576404724] [ERROR] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 625, in lambda_handler
    return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 240, in lambda_handler
    handler = global_handler or cls()
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.app_module = importlib.import_module(self.settings.APP_MODULE)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

In the log file, **[ERROR] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'** is generated. But I have app.py is present where I have written the codes.

The structure of the file is:

```
  |__RDS_Postgres_Zappa 
     |__ virtual_env 
     |__src     
     │  ├── __init__.py
     │  └── app.py
     │  └── database.ini
     └── zappa_settings.json
```

Python version is Python3.8 and zappa version is 0.55.0

I don't know what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you should use `src.app` in your `"app_function": "app.app",`